# How to attach javadocs to Eclipse Java EE Juno?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, eclipse-juno

I downloaded Eclipse Java EE juno from here http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr1

I also have javadocs : jdk-6u25-fcs-bin-b04-apidocs-04_Apr_2011

Now I want to attach these javadocs to Eclipse, but unfortunately after a lot of searches and
tries I couldn't do this. How can I attach javadocs to Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Edit. There you should be able to choose javadoc location for jars.

Comment: the javadoc that i've downloaded was a RAR file which contains some folder and an 'index.html' file,
but now when I select the folder , it caused an error : Target is not a JDK Root. Java executable was not found

so should I download any other patches of javadoc ???

Comment: Usally javadocs for jre/jdk comes from internet. Why do you need to download this rar?

Comment: let me download it again and try the new one.
which one do I need to download ??? jdk or jre ?